# iOS Unity Asset Bundle Download Restrictions - Particle Effects, Animations, and Animated Assets

Tags: ios, animation, bundle, unity-game-engine, particles

On the Official Unity Website ([this article](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/iphone-Downloadable-Content)) they have a list of instructions for creating and persisting downloadable asset bundles on iOS devices. The following is an excerpt which arose some questions for me:

> Please note: Any game scripts included in downloadable content must
>   also be present in the main executable.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580940/does-apple-allow-to-download-opengl-shaders-in-ios-game-at-runtime) is the closest answer I kind find on the subject however shaders have dynamically executed code while animated assets and particles, to my knowledge, are executed from code already compiled within the Unity Game Engine.

Are particles, character animations and animated assets considered to be 'game scripts' by Apple? I would like to include these along with several static assets such as textures and meshes as downloadable content within my game.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your question here, and I never worked with In App purchase. But I am developing with Unity and iPad and I **can** download AssetBundles with [no **major**](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/470240/using-async-webrequest-getresponse.html) problems, so...

> Are particles, character animations and animated assets considered to be 'game scripts' by Apple?

All that sure can be "added" later through downloading asset bundles. But maybe you'd need to make this control outside of Apple's purchase system, even while using it. All it takes is making a wrapper.